# publish .net core and angular2 in iis

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, iis, publish

I have a .NET Core web Application with some class library as my layers (Data layer/Business Layer/ASP.NET Core Layer).
I used Angular2 in my project.
When I publish my project in IIS, parts that angular call WebApi (to get information from Database SQL server), it doesn't work.
I get error:

> ERR_Connection_Reset"

I followed this tutorial:
https://blog.3d-logic.com/2016/06/08/running-asp-net-core-applications-with-iis-and-antares/
but no result.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your models may have looping references. Core does not support many-to-many out of the box and I find hand-rolling models without creating looping references to be difficult.

If this is the case, try changing your Startup.cs file `ConfigureServices()` method. The line `services.AddMvc();` should be changed to this:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```